# Free body diagram of rod in sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

I was finding the free body diagram part of dynamics quite easy until I found this question , Here's how it goes :

> A rod AB is placed inside a spherical shell, whose inside surface is rough. Draw the free body diagram (FBD) of the rod.
>
> [image: Rod in Spherical shell]

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: There isn't much to say as I am clueless about the direction of normal force. Friction will be across the ends(tangent), gravitational force is obviously downward.

Comment: Why is it hard? The rule is to replace connections with forces. So ask yourself, what forces might be acting here.

Answer (score 4):

Got the answer. For anyone interested here's the solution:    [image: Solution]

Comment: Great sketch. What did you use to make it?

Comment: Really? Paint . LOL ! And the subtitles are not actually subtitles they are just smaller font size stuck to the bigger ones. :)

Comment: @Simar, Could you please explain why $F_A$ is in the downward direction?   The end A of the rod would like to move downward, so I think that the since Friction tries to oppose relative motion it should act in the opposite Direction.